# Making a single {{link-to}} active in Ember

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app I have navigation bar with groups. Each unique item appears twice in the bar: in its own group and in "All Items" group:

[image: items]

If user selects Item 3 both links become active by getting `active` CSS class:

[image: item 3 selected]

How can I change my code so that the link that user has clicked on becomes active? If user opens /item/3 URL manually the first link only should be active.

Here is my code so far: http://jsbin.com/yidofayoma/3/edit?html,js,output

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('item', { path: '/item/:item_id' });
});

App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return params.item_id;  
  }
});
```

Navigation bar template:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{#link-to "index"}}Index{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>
    All items
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 1}}Item 1{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 2}}Item 2{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 3}}Item 3{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 4}}Item 4{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 5}}Item 5{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Group A
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 1}}Item 1{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 2}}Item 2{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 3}}Item 3{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Group B
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 4}}Item 4{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 5}}Item 5{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr />

{{outlet}}
```

Ember version: 2.4.2

Comment: CSS can help you in this case. add different css of different level of active menus. so the menus will have active class  but it will not look active

Comment: @murli2308 Good idea but I want to let users to click **any** link in the menu and make it active.

Answer (score 7):

Add `group` query parameter to item route:

```
App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    group: {}
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return params.item_id;  
  }
});
```

Next, add `group` query parameter to each link:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{#link-to "index"}}Index{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>
    All items
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 1 (query-params group="all")}}Item 1{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 2 (query-params group="all")}}Item 2{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 3 (query-params group="all")}}Item 3{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 4 (query-params group="all")}}Item 4{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 5 (query-params group="all")}}Item 5{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Group A
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 1 (query-params group="a")}}Item 1{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 2 (query-params group="a")}}Item 2{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 3 (query-params group="a")}}Item 3{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Group B
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 4 (query-params group="b")}}Item 4{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "item" 5 (query-params group="b")}}Item 5{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This makes only one link active. The downside is an extra query string parameter in all item URLs, e.g. `/item/5?group=all`.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/josogumaqo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4):

First, I want to say that's a very interesting question, thank you.

You may do as @pavel-chuchuva suggested, or (to avoid extra parameters and make urls user-friendly) create a separate route for each group:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('all', { path: '/all/:item_id' });
  this.route('a', { path: '/a/:item_id' });
  this.route('b', { path: '/b/:item_id' });
});
```

You may create a mixing to avoid having a 3 copies of the same code

```
var itemsRoute = Ember.Mixin.create({
  model: function(params) {
    /*return something useful*/
    return params.item_id;  
  }
});
```

And extend all, a and b routes from that mixin:

```
App.AllRoute = Ember.Route.extend(itemsRoute, {});
App.ARoute = Ember.Route.extend(itemsRoute, {});
App.BRoute = Ember.Route.extend(itemsRoute, {});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/nibacogeye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. However ideally each item should get a single canonical URL regardless of which group it belongs to: `/item/5`.

Comment: @PavelChuchuva I don't think it is possible with link-to. Only if you wish to create your own `my-link-to` component, that will somehow store information about clicked menu item (for example, save unique id in memory)